# How to check Schedule item is running in List Schedule SQL server Agent Job C#

Tags: c#, sql, schedule

I am using SQL server Agent in C#. My job has 3 Schedule, i set one Schedule runs ahead. How to check name of Schedule running. Thanks you.
This is code:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            JobSQL.Refresh();
            if (JobSQL.CurrentRunStatus == JobExecutionStatus.Executing)
            {
                List<JobSchedule> listSchedule = new List<JobSchedule>();
                foreach (JobSchedule JobSchedule in JobSQL.JobSchedules)
                {
                    if (JobSchedule.IsEnabled == true)
                    {
                        listSchedule.Add(JobSchedule);
                    }
                }

                foreach (JobSchedule item in listSchedule)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Schedule run is -----" + item.Name.ToString());
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my proplem. I just check Job.LastRunDate for my proplem